Does unlimited signing oracle leak the private key?
I am writing a PC software that uses a type of USB dongle as licensing key. The dongle functions as a signing oracle and does nothing more:
Given any message $M$, it first pads $M$ to $PadM$, then signs $PadM$ with its private key $PriK$ and outputs the signature $S$.
Every minute the PC software generates some random bytes to challenge the dongle. It shall reply with a signature $S$ that verifies successfully with the corresponding public key $PubK$. By this means the software considers the genuine dongle is present.
To prevent dongle cloning, the private key is supposed to never be disclosed. However, as the end user possesses the dongle, she can use it to sign unlimited number of messages and observe the results. Does this give her the ability to recover the private key?
I'd like to know if there's a general answer to this problem. But in particular I care about the following two signing schemes (which is supported by the dongle):

RSA2048 with PKCS #1 v1.5 padding (No ASN.1)
$PadM$ = 00 01 FF FF...FF 00 $M$ (256 bytes total)
$S$ = $PadM^d\bmod N$

Standard ECDSA with NIST P256
$PadM$ = 00 00...00 $M$ (32 bytes total)
$S$ = $ECDSA\_NIST\_P256(PadM)$



may I ask about the quality of the random number generator? Especially against cold and heat? ECDSA has a security problem with tiny biases on RNGs. Coins are migrating from ECDSA to deterministic ECDSA due to this problem...

@kelalaka The dongle is a black box manufactured by a third party. I don't know the quality of its RNG. Thanks for the hint.

As the user gets possession of the device, this opens up the door to side channel attacks. Power analysis, for example, can be really difficult to fully protect against.

Yes, commonly these things use smart card chips inside. Those are protected against side channels. However, it is much more secure to have a user provide a PIN to having it create a signature. I'd be more worried about the side channel scenario than leaking a private key through input / output (combinations).
